** (exit) shutdown: failed to start child: DBConnection.ConnectionPool ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call
cant connect to postgres via ecto and Postgrex with Elixir
Why I’m getting this error when trying to dynamically connect to repo?
(exit) shutdown: failed to start child: DBConnection.ConnectionPool
    ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(DBConnection.Watcher, {:watch, DBConnection.ConnectionPool.Supervisor, {DBConnection.ConnectionPool.Pool, {#PID<0.215.0>, #Reference<0.2815974209.1407844355.30737>, Postgrex.Protocol, [types: Postgrex.DefaultTypes, repo: MyApp.Repo, telemetry_prefix: [:my_app, :repo], otp_app: :testes_pay, timeout: 15000, database: "friends", port: 8080, hostname: "localhost", username: "pedri", password: "1234", pool_size: 1, pool: DBConnection.ConnectionPool]}}}, :infinity)
        ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started

insert.ex file

`{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:req)
    ct = %{
      chain: "ethereum",
      coin: "ETH",
      transaction_value: 12.345,
      transaction_charged: 1.234,
      ref: "test_ref",
      payload: "test_payload",
      public: "test_public",
      private: "test_private",
      status: false
    }
    
    default_dynamic_repo = MyApp.Repo.get_dynamic_repo()

    {:ok, repo} =
      MyApp.Repo.start_link(
        name: :gatinhos,
        hostname: "localhost",
        username: "pedri",
        password: "1234",
        pool_size: 1
      )
    
    try do
      MyApp.Repo.put_dynamic_repo(repo)
      MyApp.Repo.all(Post)
    after
      MyApp.Repo.put_dynamic_repo(default_dynamic_repo)
      Supervisor.stop(repo)
    end
  `
  

*application.ex file*

`defmodule TestesPay.Application do

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Dotenv.load()
    children = [
      MyApp.Repo,
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Myapp.Supervisor]  # Add a space after name:
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end`

mix.exs file

`defmodule TestesPay.MixProject do

  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :testes_pay,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.16",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger, :postgrex],
      mod: {TestesPay.Application, []}
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:req, "~> 0.5.0"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.6"},
      {:postgrex, "~> 0.19.1"},
      {:rustler, "~> 0.34.0"},
      {:dotenv, "~> 3.0"},
      {:decimal, "~> 2.0"}
      # {:dep_from_hexpm, "~> 0.3.0"},
      # {:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git", tag: "0.1.0"}
    ]
  end
end

I dont need to load it dynamic, but I couldnt also connect via the default connection in the Ecto docs via config.,exs
i’m able to give cli commands suach as Ecto migrate etc and it connects to db make changes, but querying it by code isnt working

How do you run this code?

the problem was that, I was executing as a script instead of running the full aplication with mix run. And acessing the db during compilation was also throwing that error

What is the mix command you're using? It's likely you're not actually running any setup of the application which means the database connection isn't being created.
